# IE11 XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, activex

So I have a website that uses ActiveX and js. When I try to run this website on a PC then I get this error. But when I run it on my laptop then it runs as it should.

Do you know about any "secret" settings in IE or Windows that could change the outcome? Or why does my laptop doesn't get this error?